# Unable to login to WP using Selenium in PyCharm because of cookies

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium-webdriver, pycharm

This is my code:

```
`class base_test(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        warnings.simplefilter('ignore', ResourceWarning)
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.maximize_window()

def test1(self):
        driver = self.driver
        f=Funciones_Globales(driver)
        f.nav("WP link",t)
        f.Tab_Xpath_valida("//input[@id='user_login']", "username", "password", t)`
```

And wp says i can't login because of cookies.

Is there a way to accept cookies without a button to click?

All I need is for a way to allow cookies so I can login.

Comment: What is **WP**?

Comment: you answer is precisely here: https://www.guru99.com/handling-cookies-selenium-webdriver.html 

WP: i feel like it's WordPress

Comment: Please don't scream (with upper case letters). Warm welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Serious pro-tip: Avoid using anything like that in/via PyCharm. The platform is unstable and it is a better investment to learn how to run Selenium directly.  Been on PyCharm for 10 years, when you submit a bug you need to rally votes for them to work on it.  So as a result the platform is very buggy.